# Unable to redirect to particular page when click on toast notification in windows phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a chat application...

For getting toast notifications i am sending notification uri to Microsoft server...

When i close app if i am getting toast notifications,i click on toast then it is redirecting to particular page that i specified..

But when i deactivating from the app and if i got any toast notification and i click on it then it is not redirecting to that chat page but redirecting to the page that i deactivating from the app.

I hope you understand the scenario..

How to redirect to that page when i deactivated the app also?

Comment: Are you using Fast App Resume? Otherwise a deactivated app should be relaunched on toast tap.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Fast App Resume you'll want to read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx and even play with the sample code right at the end of that article.

You should be getting a `Navigated` event which you can handle to refresh your content / redirect to the right place. If it isn't working for you and you aren't cancelling any in-progress navigations during app resume then there may be an edge case bug that you're hitting.